# Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am learning Hibernate framework. When I am doine @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotation practice i got an error.

here is my code below. Could you tell me a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.map;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
public class Question {

@Id
@Column(name="question_id")
private int questionid;

private String question;

@OneToMany
private List<Answer> answers;


public int getQuestionid() {
    return questionid;
}


public void setQuestionid(int questionid) {
    this.questionid = questionid;
}


public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}


public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}


public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
    return answers;
}


public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
    this.answers = answers;
}



public Question(int questionid, String question, List<Answer> answers) {
    super();
    this.questionid = questionid;
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
}


public Question() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

here is another class:

```
package com.map;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Answer {

@Id
@Column(name="answer_id")
private int answerid;

private String answer;

@ManyToOne
private Question question;
public int getAnswerid() {
    return answerid;
}
public void setAnswerid(int answerid) {
    this.answerid = answerid;
}
public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}
public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}

public Question getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
public void setQuestion(Question question) {
    this.question = question;
}



public Answer(int answerid, String answer, Question question) {
    super();
    this.answerid = answerid;
    this.answer = answer;
    this.question = question;
}
public Answer() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}   
}
```

and this a main() class where code is executed:

```
package com.map;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import java.util.*;

public class Mapping {
public static void main(String arg[]) {

Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    
Question q = new Question();
q.setQuestionid(1212);
q.setQuestion("What is java?");

Answer a1 = new Answer();
a1.setAnswerid(343);
a1.setAnswer("1. Java is a programming language");
a1.setQuestion(q);

Answer a2 = new Answer();
a2.setAnswerid(63);
a2.setAnswer("2. Java Robust");
a2.setQuestion(q);
    
Answer a3 = new Answer();
a3.setAnswerid(363);
a3.setAnswer("3. Java have Secure");
a3.setQuestion(q);

List<Answer> list = new ArrayList<Answer>();
list.add(a1);
list.add(a2);
list.add(a3);
q.setAnswers(list);

Session s = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();

s.save(q);
tx.commit();

s.close();
factory.close();

}
}
```

and this hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hiberpractice</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property> 
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<!--  use 'class' attribute  -->
<!--  <mapping class="com.DmlPractice_Maven.Student"/> -->
<!-- <mapping class="com.DmlPractice_Maven.Address" /> -->
<!-- <mapping class="com.DmlPractice_Maven.FetchDemo" /> --> 
<mapping class="com.map.Question" />
<mapping class="com.map.Answer" />
<mapping class="com.map.Mapping" />


</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

and this a console in eclipse where error show :

````
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
    Sep 05, 2022 11:17:45 AM 
    org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
    Sep 05, 2022 11:17:45 AM 
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Sep 05, 2022 11:17:45 AM 
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl 
    buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL 
    [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hiberpractice]
    Sep 05, 2022 11:17:45 AM 
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl 
    buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
    Sep 05, 2022 11:17:45 AM 
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl 
    buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
    Sep 05, 2022 11:17:45 AM 
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
   INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
   Sep 05, 2022 11:17:45 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
   INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
   Hibernate: alter table Answer drop foreign key FK8yiifgngf37mxn437tqdab3rg
   Sep 05, 2022 11:17:46 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@7fc420b8] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: alter table Question_Answer drop foreign key FKjqes136u88wmj7sa663j69tk2
Hibernate: alter table Question_Answer drop foreign key FKnfntbvy1ra0k0ty8dagg1g2r6
Hibernate: drop table if exists Answer
Hibernate: drop table if exists Question
Hibernate: drop table if exists Question_Answer
Hibernate: create table Answer (answer_id integer not null, answer varchar(255), question_question_id integer, primary key (answer_id)) engine=InnoDB
Sep 05, 2022 11:17:48 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@724aefc3] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table Question (question_id integer not null, question varchar(255), primary key (question_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table Question_Answer (Question_question_id integer not null, answers_answer_id integer not null) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table Question_Answer add constraint UK_2ka6gbl9caaq3i3qfyxh64oha unique (answers_answer_id)
Hibernate: alter table Answer add constraint FK8yiifgngf37mxn437tqdab3rg foreign key (question_question_id) references Question (question_id)
Hibernate: alter table Question_Answer add constraint FKjqes136u88wmj7sa663j69tk2 foreign key (answers_answer_id) references Answer (answer_id)
Hibernate: alter table Question_Answer add constraint FKnfntbvy1ra0k0ty8dagg1g2r6 foreign key (Question_question_id) references Question (question_id)
Sep 05, 2022 11:17:52 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate: insert into Question (question, question_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Question_Answer (Question_question_id, answers_answer_id) values (?, ?)
Sep 05, 2022 11:17:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
Sep 05, 2022 11:17:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hiberpractice`.`question_answer`, CONSTRAINT `FKjqes136u88wmj7sa663j69tk2` FOREIGN KEY (`answers_answer_id`) REFERENCES `answer` (`answer_id`))
Sep 05, 2022 11:17:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1411)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at com.map.Mapping.main(Mapping.java:56)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1352)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hiberpractice`.`question_answer`, CONSTRAINT `FKjqes136u88wmj7sa663j69tk2` FOREIGN KEY (`answers_answer_id`) REFERENCES `answer` (`answer_id`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 20 more ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Currently Hibernate doesn't know how to map your entities. You have 2 options here to use mappedBy from `Question` (OneToMany side) or to use `@JoinColumn` from Answer(ManyToOneSide). Here you can check an article https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby about that.

Also if you want to save them from `Question` side you can used `cascadeType` and `orphanRemoval`. If you want to check more information about them - here is another article https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ .

If you want your code to work just add this annotation above your `Question` code:

```
@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "question",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<Answer> answers;
```